# Include \t character in facet strip text with custom labeller

Tags: r, ggplot2

**UPDATE:** After posting the issue to the [ggplot2 GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1144), the problem is that R does not allow tab characters in graphics devices.

---

I'm trying to label the facets of my plot using a custom labeller. The text for my labels contains both \t and \n. The \n characters render correctly, but the \t produces squares.

```
tabLabeller <- function(variable, value) {
  return(paste0(as.character(value), 'Tab\tneeded  Newline\nneeded'))
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~carb, labeller = tabLabeller)
```

Here's the plot:

[image]

Session info is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] labeling_0.3     MASS_7.3-40      colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.2.4     magrittr_1.5     plyr_1.8.2      
[7] tools_3.2.0      gtable_0.1.2     reshape2_1.4.1   Rcpp_0.11.5      stringi_0.4-1    grid_3.2.0      
[13] stringr_1.0.0    digest_0.6.8     proto_0.3-10     munsell_0.4.2
```

Comment: the function you posted works for `ggplot2_1.0.1`. use `sessionInfo()` to find out your version

Comment: That's the version I'm currently using:  
    >sessionInfo()  
    R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)  
    Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)  
    Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)  
      
    locale:  
    [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8  
      
    attached base packages:  
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base  
    
    other attached packages:
    [1] ggplot2_1.0.1

Comment: maybe you have copied some extraneous and invisible characters

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean? When I run the snippet of code I posted, the label contains a square instead of the \t. I'd include a picture, but I don't have the reputation to post one yet. Where would the extraneous invisible characters have been added?

Comment: You can upload an image directly to imgur.com for example and put a link to the image in your question. Someone with higher rep can then put it inline. Does this only happen the R graphics device? Are you using R studio? Did you try to write to a PNG or PDF? I tried on my Windows machine and did not see any odd characters. Maybe it's a Mac thing?

Comment: it looks like anything passed to `labeller` ignores `\t`. They don't display the boxes in `R` for windows. you may need to uses a work-around like adding white spaces `"   "` or aligning the facet titles by adding `theme(strip.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0))`

Comment: The white space workaround is very messy for me. What I'm actually trying to do is basically hack a table into my label. I'm plotting the output of an ANOVA and want my label to recreate the ANOVA table (Contrast, F Statistic, P Value) -- so I have a 3x3 set of strings whose info I want to be aligned. If I do it with whitespace, I have to manually figure out how many spaces for each line for each plot (I have >10 plots).

Comment: Welcome to SO! I cannot reproduce as well, but `\t` indeed gets ignored. Here's my minimal example: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point() + labs(x = "Tab\tneeded", y = "Newline\nneeded")`. Using `"\u0009"` also doesn't help, I suspect it might be a bug.

Comment: Thanks @tonytonov! The box seems to be Mac-specific. I've updated my code based on your example, which more clearly shows the issue regardless of OS.