# Expression in ggplot2 facet labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-wrap

I would like to have an R `expression` in a `ggplot2` facet label.

Let's say I'm plotting the `tips` `data.frame`:

```
library(reshape2)
> head(tips)
  total_bill  tip    sex smoker day   time size
1      16.99 1.01 Female     No Sun Dinner    2
2      10.34 1.66   Male     No Sun Dinner    3
3      21.01 3.50   Male     No Sun Dinner    3
4      23.68 3.31   Male     No Sun Dinner    2
5      24.59 3.61 Female     No Sun Dinner    4
6      25.29 4.71   Male     No Sun Dinner    4
```

as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
sp <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + 
         geom_point(shape=1) + 
         facet_wrap(~sex, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Instead of having "Female" and "Male" as facet labels I would like to have:
"*Female* subjects" and "*Male* subjects", respectively. As far as I know italicizing a label in R is achieved through the `expression` function, but I don't know how to combine that with `facet_wrap`.

Comment: You could use a custom function, you can use with the labeller argument, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923852/include-t-character-in-facet-strip-text-with-custom-labeller)

Comment: It's not clear to me how you get the labeller argument of facet_grid to replace the factor with an expression and have the facets in rows with the labels on top, as in my example (rather than on the side as in facet_grid labels for rows).

Comment: Did you check this topic ? It might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037843/how-to-use-italics-for-facet-labels-in-ggplot2

Comment: It's close but my labels are compound - an italicized word followed by an non-italicized one. I don't see how I can achieve that with element_text of theme

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks overly complicated, but works. You'll have to use `facet_grid` though.

```
make_label <- function(value) {
  x <- as.character(value)
  bquote(italic(.(x))~subjects)
}

plot_labeller <- function(variable, value) {
  do.call(expression, lapply(levels(value), make_label))
}

ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  facet_grid(.~sex, labeller = plot_labeller)
```

[image]

Comment: I knew it had to be a function but could't get it working. Any thoughts on why this doesn't work with facet_wrap?

Comment: @RHA `facet_wrap` does not support custom labellers as is (I don't know why), but there is a low-level workaround as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282897/how-to-add-expressions-to-labels-in-facet-wrap).

Answer (score 10):

As of `ggplot2` `2.1.0`:

```
data(tips, package="reshape2")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  facet_wrap(~sex, ncol=1, 
             labeller=label_bquote(.(levels(tips$sex)[sex])~subjects))
```

Comment: Fails with the error `Error in levels(tips$sex)[sex] : could not find function "["` somehow the bquote seems to be evaluated in an empty environment? Not sure if this is a bug or a feature of a new ggplot2 version.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for R 4.0.3 and ggplot2 3.3.2

```r
library(ggplot2)
data(tips, package="reshape2")
tips$sex = as.character(tips$sex)
sp <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  facet_wrap(~sex, ncol = 1, labeller = label_bquote(italic(.(sex))~subjects))
sp
```

It uses `label_bquote` as suggested by @Stéphane Laurent but does not require converting levels into the correct character within the bquote which failed for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I like the `label_parsed` function. It works with labels in a `factor`:

```
data(tips, package="reshape2")
library(ggplot2)
tips %>%
  mutate(sex = factor(sex,
                      levels = c("Female", "Male"),
                      labels = c(expression(italic(Female)~Subjects), 
                                 expression(italic(Male)~Subjects)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  facet_wrap(~sex, ncol = 1,labeller = label_parsed)
```

This returns

[image: Link to output]